# How to view total CPU and memory usage of per system user in Linux

Tags: linux, memory, cpu, cpu-usage, user

I know the top command to see the process of CPU and memory usage, but some users of the system can generate a lot of processes, if I wanna know total CPU and memory usage of an user,I must count it by my own,so,is there a command which can view total CPU and memory usage of per system user in Linux，and order by system username?

Comment: well by pressing u in the top command you can see the users and their processes.

Comment: From user [Mohammad Rahimi](https://superuser.com/users/950805/mohammad-rahimi): There is a system load indicator for toolbar which you can config to show overall CPU and usage.  [System Load Indicator](https://askubuntu.com/questions/839211/how-to-install-system-load-indicator-in-ubuntu-16-10), [Multiload-ng](http://www.webupd8.org/2016/08/alternative-system-monitor-applet-for.html)

Comment: Nowadays, looking at cgroups is probably the best way to get meaningful values.

Answer (score 7):

I don't think there's a direct way of doing it - but one way would be to parse the output of top. The following

```
top -b -n 1 -u username | awk 'NR>7 { sum += $9; } END { print sum; }'
```

does just that. For each process in top (for a given user) awk will strip the 9th delimited field (i.e. CPU %) 7 lines down (i.e. start of the top table) for each line, then sum them. Saves you fiddling about at least!

A couple of discussions around this...

[Howtoforge](https://www.howtoforge.com/community/threads/getting-cpu-usage-per-user.25405/), [Stackexchange](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/120570/how-can-i-monitor-cpu-usage-by-user)

Comment: The number of lines to skip depends on the number of cores installed. use `6 + n_cores` to skip all. For my version of top (3.3.10), it is also the 7th field that contains the CPU usage.

Answer (score 2):

Complementing @hygris command, we can add the following and have the information for all the users at the same time:

```
top -b -n 1  |\
 awk ' BEGIN{OFS="\t"} 
 NR>7{ sum[$2] += $9; t += $9;} 
END {print "user","%CPU" ; for (u in sum){print u,sum[u]}print "total",t}'
```

The above command will print the total at the end.

If you want to add the memory:

```
 top -b -n 1  |\
  awk ' BEGIN{OFS="\t"} 
     NR>7 { sum[$2] += $9; t += $9; mem[$2] += $10; tm += $10} 
     END {print "user","%CPU","%MEM" ; for (u in sum){
         print u"\t"sum[u]"\t"mem[u];} print "total",t,tm}'
```

Then, of course, you can pipe and sort the output if that is your goal.